# Merge two bash history files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

Let's say I have two bash history files as follows:

**history1.txt**:

```
    1  ls
    2  cd foo
...
  921  history > history1.txt
```

**history2.txt**:

```
  154  vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  155  service nginx restart
...
 1153  history > history2.txt
```

I knew I could easily write a bash script to merge these two files together so that the resulting file contains line 1 to 1153 without duplicate history entries... like the following bash scripts:

**merge.sh**

```
HEAD=`head -n 1 history2.txt | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'`
sed -n -e "1,/$HEAD/p" history1.txt > merged.txt
sed -e "1,$ s/$HEAD//" -e '/^\s*$/d' history2.txt >> merged.txt
```

But I spent way more time than I'd like to admit trying to find a way to accomplish this using only unnamed pipes, sed, and/ or any other common Linux utils **WITHOUT variables and command substitution (`command`)**.  I didn't have any success :(

Any Linux shell gurus or sed masters know if this is possible?

NOTE:  I know the merge.sh script will not work for all edge cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand that correct, you simply have 2 files with no duplicate entries (though not sure about it).

So you don't need `sed` or something here. Just:

```
cat history1.txt history2.txt | sort -n > output
```

If you have duplicates:

```
cat history1.txt history2.txt | sort -n -u > output
```

Comment: Thanks, this does what I want and avoids sed altogether, and is more foul proof in the cases where the two histories don't overlap at all.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you want to add entries to your history file? Did you consider using the built in `history -r` ?

```
$ cat foo
echo "history"
$ history | tail -n 5
 1371  rm foo
 1372  tail .bash_history > foo
 1373  vim foo 
 1374  cat foo
 1375  history | tail
$ history -r foo
$ history | tail -n 5
 1374  cat foo
 1375  history | tail
 1376  history -r foo
 1377  echo "history"
 1378  history | tail
```

Maybe give `$ help history` a look in case there is something that fits your needs.

Comment: history -r nor any of the built-in options relate to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to learn the right tools to use to solve problems in UNIX as there are many wrong ways that LOOK like they solve a given problem but actually are slow, dangerous, non-portable, fragile, etc., etc.

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. shell is for manipulating files and processes and sequencing calls to UNIX tools, that is all. For general purpose text manipulation, the standard UNIX tool is awk.

The following is untested since you didn't provide sample input/output that we could run a tool against to test but it will be close if not exactly correct:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {file1[$1]=$0;next}
{
    for (i=(prev+1); i<$1; i++) {
        print file1[i]
    }
    print
    prev = $1
}
' history1.txt history2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create the flie like this

```
  1  ls
  2  cd foo
  921  history > history1.txt

  154  vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  155  service nginx restart
  1153  history >> history1.txt
```

now everything, both historys, are in 1 file.

use the cut command to select only the command lines end cut out the line numbes like. (-d is for cutting on spaces, -f is for selecting from colum 4 till the end)

```
cut -d " " -f 4- histroy1.txt > temp.txt
```

now you have all the commands in one document in the temp.txt file.
if you then use sort and uniqe to like

```
sort temp.txt |uniq
```

you get all the uniq commands you used in the 2 history files in 1 file.